# Python 3.8.1 subprocess call/Popen methods not working

Tags: subprocess, python-3.8

I recently updated my python package from 3.6.8 to 3.8.10 , from what I've read there is no much difference between the versions.
But I've encountered some problems in my code speficially with the subprocess.Popen() method not working as expected.

```
commands = ["sc start " + service_name_string]
command_executions = 
subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for cmd in commands:
    command_executions.stdin.write(str(cmd + "\n").encode())
    time.sleep(1)
 command_executions.stdin.close()
```

another option
or another example is running the following command :

```
 uninstall_process = subprocess.call(uninstall_string,shell=True)
```

this really puzzling me because there is no problem or exception (i did not inlcude the exception wrapping)

Comment: @matt i expect to be able to stop the specified service , which isn't happening , it's not a matter of permissions since the python is running as system user ( on windows)

Comment: You'lre expecting `"sc start " + service_name_string` to stop a service?

Comment: Can you try the more concise and newer `subprocess.run(["sc", "start", service_name_string])`

Comment: @matt that might help  with that specific instance , what if i need to run a series of commands unrelated to each other , but that need to follow one after the other ? should i not use the stdin.write ?

Comment: @matt sorry , i expect the "sc start" to start a service , but same goes for "sc stop"

Comment: " should i not use the stdin.write ?" Right, you should not. It is adding complications and there already seems to be some confusion about the shell argument.

Comment: As it may seem obvious i'm running on windows systems (7/8/10 and servers) and from what i read it seems i need to use the Shell=True flag

Comment: what i need to run that list of commands specifically through "cmd.exe" windows ? how do i go about that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240327/discussion-between-bored002-and-matt).

Comment: What you should do, is come up with a list of commands that are representative of what you would like to run. Include that in your question. That way somebody can help you solve the problem. Eg. service start/stop and maybe include a common window service. A concise an runnable example is best.

Comment: "...and from what i read it seems i need to use the Shell=True flag " The Shell=True means that python will use a shell. If you're starting cmd.exe, then *you're* starting the shell.